# Hard SQL Update query with aggreration

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Structure:

```
Auto(model int (key),year int (key),country varchar)
Store(name varchar(key),country varchar,model int (key),price int)
```

Updating stores that only sells models that are not manufactured in the country that the store exists in, in this way: if the price of the model in the store is maximal in relation to all models in all stores of the same country, then change the price with the average of all the prices of the same model in all the stores of the same country. (Auto.country is where it manufactured).

Thats where I am at. not sure if its correct.

```
UPDATE ... 
SET ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE model in 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT model 
    FROM Auto,Store 
    WHERE Auto.model=Store.model 
        AND Auto.country!=Store.country
    )
```

Can't figure this out.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: post your tried sql query?

Comment: I will but its a very small part of the answer.

Comment: which rdbms are you using ?

Comment: Oracle, but any rdbms will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

break it down.

stores which sell domestic cars

```
SELECT store_id FROM Store s JOIN Auto a USING (model) 
WHERE a.country = s.country
```

stores which sell *ONLY* foreign cars

```
SELECT store_id from Store where store_id NOT IN (
    SELECT store_id FROM Store s JOIN Auto a USING (model) 
    WHERE a.country = s.country
)
```

update

```
UPDATE Stores
SET ...
WHERE store_id IN (
    SELECT store_id from Store where store_id NOT IN (
        SELECT store_id FROM Store s JOIN Auto a USING (model) 
        WHERE a.country = s.country
    )
)
```

- i just noticed that you use name instead of store_id

Also your table schema is not in proper normal form.  Store.name and Store.country duplicate.  You should consider having...

```
Store (id, name, country)
Auto (id, model, year, country)
Store_Auto (store_id, auto_id, price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to update `Store` rows, so ...

```
UPDATE Store s
```

You want to set values in (only) the `price` column, so ...

```
SET price =
```

... and you want the price to be the average for the car model in the store's country, so ...

```
  ( SELECT AVG(price)
    FROM Store s2
    WHERE s2.model = s.model AND s2.country = s.country )
```

You want to do this only for rows having the maximum price for their country, so ...

```
WHERE s.price = (
  SELECT MAX(price)
  FROM Store s3
  WHERE s3.country = s.country AND s3.model = s.model
)
```

... and only for stores that do not sell any domestic models, so ...

```
AND s.name NOT IN (
    SELECT name
    FROM
      Store s4
      JOIN Auto
        ON s4.model = Auto.model
    WHERE
      s4.country = Auto.country
)
```